# How to get the text using Selenium Java that is generated after pressing a button?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to capture the text that is produced after clicking one of the links. But instead what i end up doing is capturing the text of the link.

Snippet of the code I am using:

```java
driver.navigate().to("https://demoqa.com/links");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/p[3]/a")).click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'linkResponse\']")).getText());
```

I have been trying to use `getText()`. But i don't know how to get text generated from the link.

Snapshot of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within the [DEMOQA](https://demoqa.com/links) website to click on the link with text ***Create*** and print the generated text you need to you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demoqa.com/links");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Created"))).click();
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[./b]"))).getText());
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Link has responded with staus 201 and status text Created
  ```